# show row chart after clicking a other chart (dc.js)

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have two row charts and need to show the 2nd chart after i clicked (selectetd one) on the first row chart. how can i make it?

I can't add a js fiddle, because i'm getting my data from a database.

```
 var TestCaseRow = dc.rowChart("#TestCaserowchart");
 var TestCaseDim = perfData.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.TestCase;
 });
 var clickGroup = TestCaseDim.group().reduceCount(function (d) {
     return d.x;
 });        
 var filtered_groupTestCase = remove_empty_bins(clickGroup);

 TestCaseRow
    .width(1100)
    .height(filtered_groupTestCase.all().length*18)
    .margins({ top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
    .dimension(TestCaseDim)
    .group(filtered_groupTestCase)
    .elasticX(true);

//my other row chart 
var testscriptRow = dc.rowChart("#testscriptrowchart");
var testscriptDim = perfData.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.TestScript;
});

var ClickTestscriptGroup = testscriptDim.group().reduceCount(function (d) {
    return d.x;
});
var filtered_groupTestScript = remove_empty_bins(ClickTestscriptGroup);
testscriptRow
    .width(1100)
    .height(filtered_groupTestScript.all().length*40)
    .margins({ top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
    .dimension(testscriptDim)
    .group(filtered_groupTestScript)
    .elasticX(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register an event-handler on the first chart with `.on('filtered', function(chart, filter){...})`. Within that function, check if the 2nd chart is displayed and if it is not, do whatever you need to do to display it.

Comment: I tried this but it shows my 2nd chart before i'm clicking .on('filtered', function(chart, filter)
   {
   TestCaseRow
            .width(1100)
            .height(filtered_groupTestCase.all().length*18)
            .margins({ top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
            .dimension(TestCaseDim)
            .group(filtered_groupTestCase)
            .elasticX(true)
   .colors(ColorTest);
   
   });
 -> i added here he code from the 2nd chart is this correct?

Comment: The filtered event may get called when the chart is set up. You need to test in the event handler that it is the right time to set up the chart you want. If you put together a JSFiddle, someone will probably be able to show you exactly how to do this.